# Does the REST API (official) support custom post types?

Tags: php, api, rest-api

Having browsed the official [WordPress REST API](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/) site - and looking at the various endpoints - I cannot find information of custom post types. I appreciate there is the [WordPress REST API Plugin](http://v2.wp-api.org) that appears to add support for CPT's - but does the official API support them?

If not - is there a reason for this?

Comment: you will have to define "official"

Comment: what about [this](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/types/)?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is here http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/custom-content-types/

Comment: sorry guys, links hadn't worked - official as far as I can tell is the first link

Comment: @stims - thanks but I've already mentioned that in my question - I'm not asking about the plugin

Comment: the plugin is official, and it should support

Comment: .... maybe a better question here can be something like "how to create or query CPT if the rest api plugin

Comment: Are you asking about wordpress.com (the hosted platform) or wordpress.org (the downloadable software)? Your first link is to wordpress.com, which is not the same thing as the REST API that's part of the downloadable version of WordPress.

Comment: Assuming you're interested in developing for the self-hosted version of WordPress, then you need the REST API plugin in order for it to be useful. It's being merged into WordPress core over time, but the plugin is still separate and must be installed. .

Comment: @Dalton - you're assumption is correct. Thanks for the explanation it makes more sense now. Put that in an answer and I'll happily mark is as correct. I'm going to set up a test environment and give it a go.

Comment: @Dalton - one more thing - say I'm building an Angular site, using the Wp-Api to retrieve posts / pages - does the WordPress Wp-Admin still work the same - the client can edit their content through this rather than having to build a custom backend that connects to the API and POSTS/PUTs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification in the comments. The confusion is between the WordPress.com hosted API and the WordPress.org REST API project, which are different. The WordPress.com API was developed by Automattic and is only available for websites hosted on the WordPress.com platform. There's some overlap in functionality, but that's not the documentation you're looking for if you're building a site with the downloadable version of WordPress from WordPress.org.

The official documentation for the REST API plugin that works with downloadable WordPress is [here](http://v2.wp-api.org/). Parts of the plugin have already been integrated into WordPress core, and it looks like the another big chunk is on track to be [merged in an upcoming WordPress release](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/10/08/rest-api-merge-proposal-part-2-content-api/), probably 4.8 or 4.9.

To answer your question about whether the API supports custom post types, it definitely does! When you're registering your custom post type with the `register_post_type` function, add the following argument:

`'show_in_rest' => true`

That's the minimumum amount of code, which makes your post type part of the public API. You can do things like [add custom namespaces and authentication functions](http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/custom-content-types/), but that's not necessary if your API is public and you're just getting started.

To answer your follow-up question about using the API with Angular - yes, the WP-Admin dashboards all work exactly the same when the API is enabled, you can edit using the dashboard and use the API as a read-only client.

Good luck with your project and have fun!